# How to store original data while updating state react

Tags: reactjs, filter, use-state, updating, react-context

im working on a feedback app,and im updating an state by filtering it, so i can click on a tag and display the feedbacks filtered by tags, im passing the values through context

```
 const handleFiltering = (category) => {
    

    const filteredData = cardInfo?.filter((item: feedbackTypes) => item.categories === category);
    setCardInfo(filteredData);
};

return <DataContext.Provider value={{ cardInfo }}>{children}</DataContext.Provider>;
```

and these are, the card component (where im rendering the feedbacks)

```
const NewTable: FC = (): JSX.Element => {
const { cardInfo, setCardInfo } = useContext(DataContext);

return (
    <>
        <Stack spacing={6} mt={4} ml="38.2vw">
            {cardInfo ? (
                cardInfo?.map((values: feedbackTypes) => (
                    <div key={values._id}>
                        <Link
                            to={{
                                pathname: '/editFeedback',
                                state: {
                                    id: values._id,
                                    title: values.title,
                                    feedback: values.text,
                                    category: values.categories
                                }
                            }}
                        >
                            <Card 
                             title={values.title} 
                             feedback={values.text} 
                             cardId={values._id} 
                             category={values.categories} />
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                ))
            ) : (
                <EmptyCard />
            )}
        </Stack>
    </>
);
```

};

and the components where the tags are rendered

```
const NavBar = () => {
const { cardInfo, handleFiltering, permanentData } = useContext(DataContext);

return (
    <>
        <Flex direction="row">
            <Box borderRadius="10px" className={styles.leftCard}>
                <Heading fontSize="xl" color="white" mt={14} ml={6}>
                    Frontend Mentor
                </Heading>
                <Text mt={2} ml={6}>
                    Feedback Board
                </Text>
            </Box>
            <Box borderRadius="10px" className={styles.leftCardSort}>
                <Heading fontSize="xl" color="white" mt={10} ml={6}></Heading>
                <Text ml={4} className={styles.tagSort}>
                    {permanentData?.map((values, idx) => (
                        <div key={idx}>
                            <Tag
                                className={selectedTag?.includes(values as never) ? styles.tagSelected : styles.tagUnselected}
                                onClick={(e) => {
                                    handleFiltering(values);
                                    handleBtnStyle(values as never);
                                }}
                            >
                                {values}
                            </Tag>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </Text>
            </Box>
```

whenever i click on each tag, the feedbacks that contain those tags are filtered correctly, but when i click on another tag after selecting one, it does not render the other feedbacks until i click on 'All' (and thats because im fetching all the data again), i dont know how could i re render other feedbacks after i already clicked on one, because the feedback component needs to be filtered just like the tag is filtering them by categories, i dont know what logic to follow from here on

[first tag selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XYZ8.png)

[second tag selected after the first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1m3s.png)

Comment: I think you can use different state, or just filter the state without saving the filtered data.

Comment: Agreed. Store the filter value in state and provide the derived filtered `cardInfo` state to the app, leaving the `cardInfo` state intact as the source of truth.

Comment: but that would mean different states with different values for each component, i can't render the feedbacks dynamically while clicking the tag component, i tried it, but the feedbacks are not being filtered by the tags, because the feedbacks component is using the filtered state, while the tags component is using the untouched one

Comment: I don't follow. Aren't all the components currently using the same filtered by tag state? The proposed solution just moves where the filtering is done so the *real* state is left unmutated so it doesn't need to be fetched again just to view all.

Comment: im sorry, im either not understanding or i didn't explain myself well, now i have an state where the filtering is being done (tags component/NavBar), and the original untouched one on the fedback component(NewTable), but the list remains and no filtering is shown in the NewTable component since it has an untouched state, because they don't share the same data being rendered, im sorry if im having too much trouble understanding

Comment: No worries. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox of your code that we could inspect and debug live?